# R scatterplot3d error with new column data

Tags: r

```
> library(scatterplot3d)
> scatterplot3d(iris$Sepal.Length,iris$Petal.Length,iris$Petal.Width)
> iris.2<-(iris)
> iris.2["Sepal.Area"]<-(pi*iris.2$Sepal.Length*iris.2$Sepal.Width)
> scatterplot3d(iris.2$Sepal.Length*iris.2$Sepal.Width*iris.2$Sepal.Area)
Error in xyz.coords(x = x, y = y, z = z, xlab = xlabel, ylab = ylabel,  : 
'x', 'y' and 'z' lengths differ
```

The first scatterplot works, but when I try it with the new column Sepal.Area, it doesn't work.  I am creating the new column based upon the existing columns, so how can the lengths differ?  What is the fix for this to allow me to use scatterplot3d( )?

Comment: Look at your code. In the second call, you've got one argument, the product of Length*Width*Area. Since the `y` and `z` arguments are missing, their lengths are 0, which is different from the length of `x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have asterisks (*) separating the elements in the second scatterplot3d function. You should use commas (,) as you did in the first scatterplot3d function.

```
scatterplot3d(iris.2$Sepal.Length,iris.2$Sepal.Width,iris.2$Sepal.Area)

library(scatterplot3d)

scatterplot3d(iris$Sepal.Length,iris$Petal.Length,iris$Petal.Width)

iris.2<-(iris)

iris.2["Sepal.Area"]<-(pi*iris.2$Sepal.Length*iris.2$Sepal.Width)

scatterplot3d(iris.2$Sepal.Length,iris.2$Sepal.Width,iris.2$Sepal.Area)
```